# How do I remove the extra bash-3.2$ from shell-mode?

Tags: bash, emacs, prompt

**Summary**

The first line of shell-mode has an extra `bash-3.2$` prompt before my custom `dotfiles (master)$` prompt.

I tried writing `PROMPT_COMMAND=''` in my `~/.bashrc` according to an earlier [Stack Overflow](https://superuser.com/questions/31533/how-do-i-fix-my-prompt-in-emacs-shell-mode) post, but `bash-3.2$` continues to display anyway.

**Steps to reproduce**

```
$ emacs
M-x shell-mode RET
```

**Expected**

```
dotfiles (master)$ RET
dotfiles (master)$ RET
dotfiles (master)$ RET
```

**Observed**

```
bash-3.2$ dotfiles (master)$ RET
dotfiles (master)$ RET
dotfiles (master)$ RET
```

**Configuration**

- [.emacs](https://github.com/mcandre/dotfiles/blob/master/.emacs)
- [.emacs_bash](https://github.com/mcandre/dotfiles/blob/master/.emacs_bash)
- [.bash_profile](https://github.com/mcandre/dotfiles/blob/master/.bash_profile)
- [.bashrc](https://github.com/mcandre/dotfiles/blob/master/.bashrc)
- [.bashrc.d/](https://github.com/mcandre/dotfiles/tree/master/.bashrc.d)
- [.bash_profile.d/](https://github.com/mcandre/dotfiles/tree/master/.bash_profile.d)

**System**

```
$ specs emacs bash brew os
specs --version
0.19

emacs --version
GNU Emacs 24.4.1
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
GNU Emacs comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You may redistribute copies of Emacs
under the terms of the GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file named COPYING.

bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin14)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

brew --version
0.9.5

system_profiler SPSoftwareDataType | grep 'System Version'
    System Software Overview:
      System Version: OS X 10.10.3 (14D136)
```

Also posted on [Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/34uyrt/how_do_i_remove_the_extra_bash32_from_shellmode/).

Answer (score 0):

Remove `\v` or `\V` from your `PS1` variable.

http://ss64.com/bash/syntax-prompt.html

Comment: You are correct, `PS1` is briefly set to `\s-\v\$`, and printed, before my shell configuration finishes setting it to `\W$(__git_ps1 " (%s)")$`.

On a related note, I've noticed that shell-mode often prints a prompt before waiting for programs to finish running.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was loading my git prompt with .bash_profile, but not with .bashrc, after I had changed the load style of my bash configuration for speed.

I've created https://github.com/mcandre/dotfiles/blob/master/.bashrc.d/emacs-git-prompt.sh to get the best of both worlds: fast shells, and idiomatic Emacs shell prompts!